# Why sometimes we need [attr.] prefix for binding

Tags: javascript, angular

When binding in general we only need to add `[]`

Working example:

```
<input [type]="myInputType" [(ngModel)]="myValue" />
```

But sometimes its is mandatory to use `[attr.]`

Example where `[attr.]` is mandatory:

```
<svg>
    <path [attr.fill]="part.color[attr.d]="part.d"
    [attr.transform]="part.transform"></path>
</svg>
```

I cannot determine if I need or not (only empirically by actually trying it), which is disturbing. What is the rule?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview

Comment: Thank for the link. That answer partially., but my question is not answer by this doc. I was on purpose seeking what is the difference between property and attribute from angular point of view. That is not so obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `attr.` Angular will bind to a property. 
A property isn't available in the DOM for CSS or `querySelector`.

Some properties are reflected to attributes by the element itself, which again makes it available for CSS or querying (`class`, `disabled`, ...).

See also [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

If there is no property with that name, you can only bind to an attribute. For that Angular requires `attr.`

Comment: Just adding to the answer, that is the list of which is what: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/attributeTable.html